# parsing multiple lists in bbcode?

Tags: php, regex

Hi all I have a very simple bbcode parsing system, it is currently having problems with lists within lists.

My code:

```
$find = array(
'/\[list\](.*?)\[\/list\]/is',
'/\[\*\](.*?)(\n|\r\n?)/is',
'/\[ul\](.*?)\[\/ul\]/is',
'/\[li\](.*?)\[\/li\]/is'
);

$replace = array(
'<ul>$1</ul>',
'<li>$1</li>',
'<ul>$1</ul>',
'<li>$1</li>'
);
$body = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body);
```

The problem is when you have another list inside the li tags it then completely fails to parse, screenshot showing: [image: image1]

This is how it should look: [image: images2]

I know my code is probably too simple for it but how do i adjust it so it can parse a list within a list item?

Comment: It is because of `(.*?)` matching.

Comment: You will need a recursive regex `(?R)`. Otherwise why don't you just replace all `[ul] [li]` with `<ul> <li>` if possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using Regular Expressions you have a couple of options..

1. Use PHP's [BBCode Parsing extension](https://www.php.net/bbcode)
2. Do a much simpler replacement, ie. straight up replace `[ul]` with `<ul>` etc.

I'm not saying it can't be done with Regex, just that it's not the simplest option.

Here's a still-regex based replacement:

```
$body = '[ul][li]test[/li][li]test[/li][li]test[ul][li]lol[/li][/ul][/li][li]hehe[/li][/ul]';

$find = array(
    '/\[(\/?)list\]/i',
    '/\[\*\](.*?)(\n|\r\n?)/i',
    '/\[(\/?)ul\]/i',
    '/\[(\/?)li\]/i'
);
$replace = array(
    '<$1ul>',
    '<li>$1</li>',
    '<$1ul>',
    '<$1li>'
);
$body = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body);
```

Comment: You are right, I just straight up parse the tags themselves and it works, thanks!

Comment: Check update, it's a regex that will achieve the same effect.